# Some resizing cells and some static in two UITableViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios8

I have two UITableViews in the same ViewController, one which uses dynamic height based on UILabel content size and the other where all the cells are static heights. I separated the two TableViews using tags. I tried using this:

```
self.tableView1.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

and:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (tableView.tag == 1) {
        return 114.0f;
    } else {
        if (indexPath.section == 0) {
            return 50.0f;
        } else if (indexPath.section == 2) {
            return 20.0f;
        } else {
            return 44.0f;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the dynamic cells do not change dynamically and the static height cells originally have the right height but when they scroll out of the view they then change to the default height for cells.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

When you implement:

```
  - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

You need implement both this and

```
 -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Normally It´s the same code, add this to your protect:

```
 -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {    
 if (tableView.tag == 1) {
    return 114.0f;
} else {
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        return 50.0f;
    } else if (indexPath.section == 2) {
        return 20.0f;
    } else {
        return 44.0f;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: But if I add heightForRowAtIndexPath won't this mean my cells in tableView1 will no longer be dynamically sized?

Comment: UITableViewAutomaticDimension is default value, not means than value changes in function a content. You need in this two methods calculate the height in function your label ( Uses length, uses textSizeForAttributes..). But you must provide.